# Formatação de moeda para salvar no banco de dados como DECIMAL

Tags: php, mysql

Estou usando um banco mysql, o formato do campo é `Decimal (7,2)` e ele recebe o valor de salário.
Baseado no que o usuário digita eu armazeno no banco assim:

```
str_replace(',','.', $_POST['txtSalario'])
```

Susbstituindo a vírgula por ponto.
O problema é que se ele digitar ex: 3.145,89, os banco de dados recusa pois ele entende que o primeiro ponto já é a casa decimal.
Como tratar essa entrada de dados para receber valores digitados como 3145,89 ou 3.145,89?
Estou usando o `PHP 5.3` e `mysql 5.5`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No campo input da tela editar é preciso substituir o ponto por vírgula, para que na hora de salvar a função abaixo não dê erro.

Na tela editar :

```
$valor = $valor = str_replace('.', ',',$NumValorDeconto);
```

E para salvar usei uma função para limpar.

```
public static function moeda($get_valor) {

        $source = array('.', ',');
        $replace = array('', '.');
        $valor = str_replace($source, $replace, $get_valor); //remove os pontos e substitui a virgula pelo ponto
        return $valor; //retorna o valor formatado para gravar no banco
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Não testei o código, mas você já tentou remover o ponto antes?

```
str_replace(',','.', str_replace('.','', $_POST['txtSalario']))
```

Comment: Sim, na hora que eu coloco uma função para editar o valor ele armezena o valor como 999999

Comment: Armazena 999999 quando você digitou o que antes? E qual foi o código utilizado para tratar?

Comment: Por exemplo: adicionei 2601,34 e gravei. Tudo certo. Na tela de edição eu pego esse valor do banco e coloco em um campo input. Supondo que eu não alterei nada e clico em salvar , o sistema converte pra 99999

Comment: Quando ele volta do campo o valor colocado no input é ex: 322.88. Acho que preciso resolver isso

Comment: Deu certo aqui precisava tratar o campo antes de mandar no input para resolver.

Comment: Você tratou de qual forma?

Comment: Na tela editar :  $valor = $valor = str_replace('.', ',',$NumValorDeconto);<br>E para salvar usei uma função para limpar.

Answer (score 1):

Amigo provavelmente vc já resolveu claro né...rs mais sei que alguém vai cair nesta página fazendo a mesma pesquisa estão segue um código simples e funcional!

```
  function Valor($valor) {
       $verificaPonto = ".";
       if(strpos("[".$valor."]", "$verificaPonto")):
           $valor = str_replace('.','', $valor);
           $valor = str_replace(',','.', $valor);
           else:
             $valor = str_replace(',','.', $valor);   
       endif;

       return $valor;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Como o dinheiro precisa de uma representação exata não use tipos de dados que só são aproximados como `float`. Você pode usar um tipo de dados numéricos de ponto fixo, como

```
numeric(15,2)
```

15 é a precisão (comprimento total de valor, incluindo casas decimais)
2 é o número de dígitos depois do ponto decimal
Veja Tipos [númericos no MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fixed-point-types.html) :

Esses tipos são usados ​​quando é importante preservar a exatidão como, por exemplo, dados monetários.

para validar use algo como:

```
preg_match('!^\d{1,3}(\.\d{3})*(\,\d{2})?$!', $number) || preg_match("!^\d+,\d\d$", $number);
```

Answer (score 0):

Eu tive esse problema e resolvi usando um approach diferente no formulário de entrada.

Ao invés de ter um único input para um float, divida ele em dois inputs: Um para o valor inteiro e um para o valor decimal. Faça com que o valor decimal receba como padrão 00. Neste caso, você garante que o valor será sempre dividido entre o valor inteiro e as casas decimais, e fica mais fácil de manipular depois no server-side.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CFBb5/)

Comment: Pena que essa implementação faz mal a usabilidade do teu sistema ;(